# how to count how many times a command is used [discord.js]

Tags: discord, discord.js, quick.db

Simply when people use the tutorial !ping command I want to count how many times and show it back in chat. like 'ping has been used this many times' I found something talking about quick.db but still don't know a lot. currently, the messages show as [This has been used This NaN times!!!]

```
module.exports = {
  name: 'ping',
  description: 'Ping!',
  execute (message, args, ) {
    const db = require('quick.db')
    var times = []
    db.set('times', {hello: 'hi'})
    db.add('times.used', 1)
      let timesused = times.used + 1;
      message.reply('pong');
      message.channel.send(`This has been used This ${timesused} times!!!`);
  },
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right solution for what you are trying to do is simple. Just do this.

```
const db = require('quick.db');

module.exports = {
  name: 'ping',
  description: 'Ping!',
  execute (message, args) {
    db.add('times.ping', 1); // Adding an amount of one to the countor for the ping command

    const timesUsed = db.get('times.ping'); // Getting the amount of uses 

    message.reply('pong!');
    message.channel.send('This command has been used '+timesUsed+' times!');
  },
};
```

For a better explanation please read the [Documentation](https://quickdb.js.org/overview/docs) of Quick.db.

Comment: If you have any questions let me know ^-^! Btw it would be cool if you could mark my answer as a solution.

Comment: I do have one more thing I am having problems with, is their a private message thing or do I need to do another Stack Overflow question

Comment: There are no private messages on stack overflow. You have to do another question